# How to create Word cloud in solr?

Tags: solr

I want to generate word cloud for a text field. Is it possible to get word count for each document.

For Example:

```
Row 1 : textfield = I want to generate the word cloud So that I can do work with  word cloud.
Row 2 : textfield = I want to generate the word cloud So that I can do work with  word cloud
```

I want output :

```
I(4),
Word(4)
cloud(4)
...
```

Comment: better use apache pig...

Answer (score 1):

I think, the solr faceting feature will help you: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceting

Comment: Faceting result : I(2),
Word(2)
cloud(2)  Its giving the word occurrence in the document not  the field occurrence. I tried Term Vectors that too also giving same result.

Comment: You can fokus the facet field using the `facet.field`parameter.  Faceting result shows, in how many documents this word exists. You get cloud(2), because you have to documents, where "cloud" is minimum 1x.